# What option do I have instead of GetAwaiter.GetResult() in ASP.NET MVC 4 on .NET v4.6.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on an old ASP.NET MVC 4 website running on .NET v4.6.1 that I cannot change and I am calling a web api2 using `HttpClient`.

As you know, the call requires is an async call, however everywhere else, the code is not using async, and I decided to use refit to make my life easier.

However I am forced to do the following all over the shop:

```
myRefitHttpClient.GetSomestuff(whatever).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Is there a better way than the above blocking code if you need to do sync over async?

Many thanks for any reply

Comment: I imagine the "better way" is to not do sync over async in the first place.  If I understand correctly, you're updating functionality in a legacy app but are limited to what you can change?  If the directive from team leadership is "make changes, but without making changes" then the team gets what it gets at that point.  `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` is a pretty small appendage for such a very localized change.

Comment: There are many sync-over-async patterns, depending on your exact usage. While none of them are ideal overall, one pattern may fit better than another. Can you expand your snippet to show additional call site context?

Comment: Hi yes I am limited in what I can change. I am removing calls to soap webservices and replacing with calls to a web api. That would be phase 1. If all good then may be we may be allowed to rewrite in .net 6 but for now I am removing all calls to old webservices and replace with http calls . Net 5 has a sync version but I am stuck with .net 461. The only thing I can think of without affecting the controllers that I cannot change to make async is todo sync over async but before plunging myself in this I thought I would check in case there is something else I could consider

Comment: It's a road full of pain, especially on ASP.Net classic, where there is a `SynchonizationContext`. Either go full async or don't do it at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, sync-over-async is always dangerous in .NET Framework on ASP.NET.

To avoid deadlocks, the following pattern (as described in [Figure Six of Stephen Cleary's article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development) allows you to split out your async request from your synchronous method call:

```
public SomeStuff GetSomestuff(Whatever whatever)
{
    return GetSomestuffAsync(whatever).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}

public async Task<SomeStuff> GetSomestuffAsync(Whatever whatever)
{
    // Do NOT queue a synchronization context continuation.
    return myRefitHttpClient.GetSomestuff(whatever).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

You can then verify via a unit test that your code does not deadlock with the `AsyncContext` library from Stephen Cleary by simulating a synchronization context.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Verify_DoesNotDeadlock()
{
    AsyncContext.Run(() =>
    {
        var whatever = new Whatever();
        var response = service.GetSomestuff(whatever);

        Assert.IsNotNull(response);
    });
}
```

Comment: brilliant thank you for your time and sample let me digest that article I did read before but I think it went over my head a bit.

Comment: You're welcome! There are a lot of excellent options in that article. This is the one I prefer for most asp.net sync-over-async implementations as it is fairly readable and provides an api that you can use when you eventually upgrade to .NET 6.